# Azure az container exec command not executing and not returning error

Tags: linux, azure, docker

I'm running Linux and I've pushed several docker containers up to azure as container instances. My containers seem to be working fine, all services provided by the containers are working. But when I run the `az container exec` command nothing happens, no error message.

I'm running:

```bash
az container exec --subscription mySubscription --resource-group myResource --name myContainer --exec-command "ls"
```

and then nothing...

When I put in a wrong container name I get an error, so I know that I'm reaching the container. I'm out of ideas about how to see what's going wrong, I would just say forget it and just do an ssh connection but there doesn't seem to be a way to do that.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just stop your container group, wait a few seconds, then start it again.

Answer (score 1):

Check and see if a firewall is blocking port 19390.  Opening this port might be a requirement for this command to work, although I cannot confirm this in the Microsoft documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/753676/what-ports-must-be-allowed-in-a-firewall-configura.html

Comment: I confirm. I work behind a corporate firewall and no return from exec command line and no return from the web interface /bin/bash from https://portal.azure.com. 
But at the moment, I use my smartphone as Hotspot, everything works perfectly.
So I try at home and also no problem to execute a terminal into the container event with the web interface from portal.azure.com.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to get this to work by removing port 19390 from our blocked list temporarily as well. I'm wondering if there is a way to only allow traffic from the azure ip addresses. It seems like *.azureregion.atlas.cloudapp.azure.com:19390 in the unblocked list but some firewall providers do not allow wildcards.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried launching a bash shell with your container? Try the following command:

`az container exec --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myContainer --exec-command "/bin/bash"`

Once you're the bash session is running, simply run the commands you want to:

`root@caas-83e6c883014b427f9b277a2bba3b7b5f-708716530-2qv47:/# ls`

Comment: The `--exec-command "ls` command he tried should also work just fine. Trying a different command will not fix this issue.